# Proper way to setup MVC project structure that won't have any dependencies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

Please see my below project structure.

My solution contains the following:
**TestProj.WebUI**  MVC5, Ninject for IoC to inject BLL

**TestProj.WebUI.Tests**

**TestProj.BLL** - contains Interfaces folder which holds ICustomerProvider.cs and folders like CRM, HR which hold classes like CustomerProvider.cs and UserProvider.cs

**TestProj.DAL** - EF6 DbFirst, also contains Repository folder which holds CustomerRepository.cs and Interfaces folder which holds ICustomerRepository.cs

**TestProj.Common** - Common classes

I can't figure out whether I should also add dependency injection in my BLL to inject the DAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be difficult to test your bll if if you can't mock the objects within the dal, so using interfaces and di would be useful in my opinion.

You also have the option of swapping out your dal for a different dal if you loosely couple it. The interfaces for the dal could be in the bll.

As a general rule all the dependencies should flow to your bll, not the other way round. The bll shouldn't be dependant on anything.

Regarding your model, I normally have this in a separate class library alongside the dal and bll and only use the model folder in the ui project sparingly.

A concept that could be useful is to have a facade layer for your bll. This prevents the ui having to know the intricate details of your bll, you just call the facade from your controllers.

On my own projects I have a bll facade layer that goes directly through to the dal if for example it's just a database access, or to a bll object if it performs any logic. I aim for 100% test coverage on the bll objects in particular and don't always tdd everything else (depending on the project requirements).

Another more controversial angle if you are using ef is how far you allow your IQueryable objects to propagate. I usually keep these in the dal layer only because on larger projects I do not want my bll to be dependant on ef.

I found the Microsoft application architecture guide 2.0 useful when it came out, it's a bit old now but still fairly relevant. You can find it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650706.aspx

Finally I personally don't like the terms bll and dal as they are acronyms and remind me of rich client software we used to write years ago, I usually call my bll layer logic, facade, model and names like data instead of dal in the data layer.

There are many ways of structuring a solution, but here is a VS2013 test solution based on an empty MVC project, with references set, that illustrates what I mean.

[My Test VS2013 Solution](http://www.johnsonsoftwaredesign.co.uk/downloads/Pj.MyTestProject.zip)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a descriptive response. I am just getting into TDD so I want to make sure everything is structured properly in this new template project I am building. I will do anything to somehow get an actual example project of a structure like this. I always read it and it makes sense but then when I go to implement it so many questions arise. I also get so confused when using DbFirst since almost every tutorial/example is based on code first. Then I don't get how everything eventually leads to a view model that is used in the controller. I will seriously pay to find out.

Comment: So based on what you are saying I would have a Model layer that is just for EDMX, then a data layer that has just repository classes, then a logic layer that has my data interfaces, service interfaces and service classes, then a facade layer (which I am still kind of confused about what actually goes in here. I am assuming Logic interfaces and facade classes) then finally a UI layer where my controllers can simply call from the facade layer.

Comment: Firstly don't mess with your mvc project. Add additional projects with additional class libraries along the lines we are talking about. Secondly edmx goes in your data layer not business logic layer because bll shouldn't be coupled to ef in my view. The model and interfaces for the repositories (ie the data layer) can go in bll and the data layer provides an implementation of this. If you are using ef do you have interfaces for the model in bll? I've never done it that way. The key question is do you mind ef infiltrating your bll. I don't on larger projects. Will try to find some examples.

Comment: Been thinking one possibility is to define model in a separate class library as we have been saying then edmx in data layer then use auto mapper in data layer to translate. It's of course up to you how you do it, the problem is that if you look at Microsoft examples they don't tend to separate out ef from the bll. I'll see if I can find / come up with some examples and if I do I will add the links here.

Comment: Thank you so much anything would help. Also, I think there was a misunderstanding of what I last said. I was trying to use your names to describe each individual layer. UI-basically view models and views only. Facade still not sure what it is but I know the controller talks to it directly. BLL will have business classes and interfaces. DAL has actual repository classes and interfaces. Model layer has just the edmx. Just figured I would describe what I was thinking again even though it still might be off.

Comment: This is a difficult thing to think about for which there is no right answer. However I our perspectives are still a bit different. To try to explain my viewpoint I am adding an attachment with an empty VS2013 solution which shows you the class library names and references on a typical project I would use. You might like to play around with this and see where you get to. I would like to wait for other replies on this thread rather than go off at a tangent, but please feel free to contact me directly (or ask other more specific questions on here of course) if this would help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68180/discussion-between-user2272527-and-philip-johnson).

Comment: As I was putting my new structure together a few questions arose: Do my repositories and services in my service layer reference my POCO objects in my Model layer or the auto-generated edmx objects in the Data layer. Also, since my repositories would be in my Model layer then that means my Model layer will reference my Service layer? Something about that seems strange and would be going against the diagram we were looking at earlier http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/05/12/the-n-layer-myth-and-basic-dependency-injection/

Comment: Most things reference the domain model. You should not have anything in the model apart from entities, not repositories for sure. Concrete Repositories are in the data layer interface repositories in the service layer (so you can program the service by interface). Let's have another chat tomorrow and cover any further questions you might have. You are absolutely right to make a technology spike so you can work it all out. I'll show available on my Skype when I'm, um available.